# .htaccess redirect & beautify query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

The browser request: `example.com/webApp/controller/action/?param1=param1value`

- Where the static (always the same) part of the URL is `webApp/`
- Where the dynamic part of the URL is `controller/action/?param1=param1value`. Usually it consists of `REQUEST_URI` (path consisting of varying amount of parts) and `QUERY_STRING`, and it can be anything, for example:

  - `site/index/?page=2`
  - `books/index/?page=2&sort=name`
  - `users/list`
  - `foo/bar`
  - `user/profile/posts/?page=2`
- The URLs listed above should look like this after .htaccess (what the server receives):

  - `index.php?path=site/index/page/2`
  - `index.php?path=books/index/page/2/sort/name`
  - `index.php?path=users/list`
  - `index.php?path=foo/bar`
  - `index.php?path=user/profile/posts/page/2`
- While the user sees the URLs without the `index.php` part in their browser:

  - `site/index/page/2`
  - `books/index/page/2/sort/name`
  - `users/list`
  - `foo/bar`
  - `user/profile/posts/page/2`

Basically I want to clean the `QUERY_STRING` part of the URL by replacing all `?` and `&` characters with `/` and append it to the `REQUEST_URI` dynamically.

I've been doing a lot of searches regarding this topic. Unfortunately the closest matches were examples of hardcoded `QUERY_STRING` parameters turned into paths. Instead I want to turn all `QUERY_STRING` parts (if there's any) into a path, dynamically.

My current **.htaccess** file content is the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The only missing part is cleaning the `QUERY_STRING`, as explained above. Also if the request URI is a file as listed in the code above (list of extensions),  it will not be processed via `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I have partially solved the issue by using the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.css|\.js)$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*) [OR]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?path=$1&%1=%2 [NC,L]
```

- `QUERY_STRING` is no longer appended at the end of the URL (`QSA` removed from the `RewriteRule`).
- Instead, `QUERY_STRING` is matched with the condition `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*) [OR]` and later used by including tokens `%1` and `%2` in the `RewriteRule`.
- This solution **DOES NOT** remove the `GET` parameters from the URL, but it does make sure they don't end up in `path` parameter.

  - Instead, the query string works normally and creates its own GET parameter entries (because it now starts with `&` instead of `?`. `?` is already used for the parameter `path`.
  - The situation described in the first post leads to a case where the query string is malformed because the "first parameter character `?`" is used twice. At least this my assumption..